# Discontinuity of a function at a point

Tags: tikz-arrows

In the example, I used the `arrows.meta` library to draw a discontinuous function at a point (2.4) but the result is not conclusive because it can be seen that the ends are misplaced.
How do otherwise ?

[image]

[image]

```
  \documentclass[6pt]{standalone}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows,
            arrows.meta,
            bending}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[
    restrict x to domain=-3:5, xmax=5, xmin=-3,
    restrict y to domain=-3:6, ymax=6, ymin=-3,
    x=0.5cm,
    y=0.5cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style =thick,
    major tick style=black,
    major grid style=gray,
    minor grid style=gray,
    grid=both,
    xtick={-2,...,4},
    ytick={-2,...,5},
    yticklabels={,,},
    xticklabels={,,},
    extra x ticks={-3,5},
    extra x tick label={\null},
    extra y ticks={-3,6}, 
    extra y tick label={\null},
    extra tick style={tick style={draw=none}},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    every axis x label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)},
   anchor=west,
   },
   every axis y label/.style={
   at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)},
   anchor=south,
   },
   samples=1000,
   >=stealth,
  ]

  \draw[{Circle[length=3pt]}-{Circle[length=3pt]},line width=0.8pt](2,5)--(4,3);
  \draw[{Circle[length=3pt]}-{Arc Barb [reversed,length=0.1cm]},line width=0.8pt](-2,3)--(-1,1)--(2,4);



 \node[below] at (1,0){$1$};
 \node[left] at (0,1) {$1$};
 \node[below left] at (0,0) {$0$};

 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put nodes at the coordinates instead of making the dots part of arrows. Define the appearance of dots somewhere before the picture as

```
\tikzset{dot/.style={circle,draw,fill=black,minimum size=1mm,inner sep=0mm}}
```

and replace the `\draw` commands by

```
\draw[{}-{Arc Barb [reversed,length=0.1cm]},line width=0.8pt]
  (-2,3) node[dot]{} -- (-1,1) -- (2.13,4.13);
\draw[line width=0.8pt]
  (2,5) node[dot]{} -- (4,3) node[dot]{};
```

This results in

[image]

Comment: @gernotThank you. And for the point (2,4) with the Arc Barb ?

Comment: The half circle seems to be centered on (2,4). What do you want it to look like? An unfilled circle?

Comment: The extremity of the line must exactly is the point (2,4) and therefore the center of the half circle should not be that.

Comment: As I know it, one uses an unfilled circle to indicate that the point is not part of the line. I will modify the code of my answer; if this is not what you want, you have to be more precise which symbol should be located exactly at which place.

Comment: The point (2,4) must be a point of the half-circle such that the center of the half-circle must be the middle point (2,4) and the diametrically opposite point (2,4).

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. For me it sounds as if (2,4) should be a point on the half circle, should be the center of the circle, and should also be a point of the circle on the other side. What was wrong with your original drawing? Should the junction of the line and the half circle be at the coordinate (2,4)? Was it ok otherwise?

Comment: A picture is worth all the explanations.

Comment: Is it now what you want?

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do, thank you.